# What are the odds of a librarian villager selling Mending books at tier 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm currently interested in finding a librarian villager that sells Mending enchanted books, since I have been fishing forever and it's just too slow. My logic is once I find a single Mending villager, I technically have a limitless resource of mending books, so why not give it a shot?

I have a working villager farm already, but I was wondering, what are the odds of a librarian villager spawning and being able to sell Mending books at tier 1? The wiki says the following

> The enchantment is chosen randomly, with equal chance of any enchantment type occurring and equal chance to get any level of it, so higher-leveled enchantments are as likely to get as low-leveled enchantments. The price in emeralds depends on enchantment level and "treasure" status. The possible values are 5 – 19 emeralds for Lvl I, 8 – 32 for Lvl II, 11 – 45 for Lvl III, 14 – 58 for Lvl IV, and 17 – 71 for Lvl V. For "treasure" enchantments the price is doubled. Note that the cost is capped to 64, meaning that for example Lvl V books truly range from 17 - 64 emeralds with costs at the upper end of the range being more common.

Does this mean that, there being 30 total enchantment types, I have a 1/30 chance of the librarian being a Mending seller, or is the enchanting pool made out of every enchantment at every level?

For example, taking into account only Sharpness and Infinity, and Sharpness having 5 levels, is the enchantment pool 6 or is it 2 and then if Sharpness is selected, a random level is selected?

Comment: > *I've been fishing  forever and it's just too slow* < — Until/unless the [`MC-168981` exploit](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-168981?focusedCommentId=619840&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-619840) gets patched, [you can AFK fish farm for treasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtG-2z7VYJQ) overnight; if you (rightly) regard macro scripts as botting/cheating, this **can be done** with nothing but a rock, book, or piece of tape holding down Mouse2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First the type of enchantment is selected randomly and then after that the level of enchantment is selected randomly. This means the probability of choosing mending is `1/(number of enchantments)`.

In your simplified example of Sharpness and Infinity, there is 1/2 probability of choosing Sharpness. Then the level of sharpness is determined by another random roll.

Comment: So I have a 1/30 chance of getting Mending? Wow! That's amazing!

Comment: First librarian villager I encountered was selling mending for 7 ems and was about to trade and become the richest on the server, until the kid zombies attacked, RIP mending Billy 2018-2018

Comment: The problem I have with this is you see MANY enchantments dozens of times more frequently, I don't think there's a even chance for each enchantment.  Of course the post is many years old, but for those searching and landing here.  I can see curse of the binding dozens of times in an hour and not see Mending in 2 hours.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know but I think it is (1/30)/5 if the stuff in the brackets (parentheses) is mending then you just have to try it (if you want a specific level) (the second part will work only if the first part is mending)(I'm not counting curses and trident enchantments)